# Batch: split values into separate line with specific pipe delimiter

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a report that will split into next row for each line. My data:

```
I,have,a,report,to,split,|,into,next,row
my,second,line,should,also,|,split,like,before
```

then it should be like this:

```
I,have,a,report,to,split
into,next,row
my,second,line,should,also
split,like,before
```

I have tried the script:

```
@echo off
setLocal
for /f "tokens=1 delims=.|" %%a in (input.csv) do echo %%a
for /f "tokens=2 delims=.|" %%a in (input.csv) do echo %%a
```

but the result is:

```
I,have,a,report,to,split
my,second,line,should,also
into,next,row
split,like,before
```

Anyone can help me with this? thanks in advance…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result example is wrong. This is the output from your code:

```
I,have,a,report,to,split,
my,second,line,should,also,
,into,next,row
,split,like,before
```

Note the comma at end of line 1 and 2, and at beginning of line 3 and 4

This method works:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define a variable with CR+LF ASCII chars:
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set CRLF=%%a^
%empty line 1/2%
%empty line 2/2%

rem Change each ",|," string by CR+LF characters
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.csv) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for %%N in ("!CRLF!") do echo !line:,^|,=%%~N!
)
```

Of course, you may also do it in the "traditional" **`:/`** way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%a in (input.csv) do (
   set "left=%%a"
   set "right=%%b"
   echo !left:~0,-1!
   echo !right:~1!
)
```

Comment: thanks for your help... it work for the traditional ways... it is what I'm looking for, thanks.. BTW your first method didn't split the line to the next row it still at the same line

Comment: My first code works over _the same data_ you posted here. I suggest you to copy the data _from this web page_ and then test my first code with it, and don't modify the code in any way...